# How to query data where 2 values must match

Tags: sql, oracle

(Oracle 11g)

I have a query that returns.

```
OrderNo  MyCode   Value
1234     AAA      11
1234     BBB      PPP
4732     AAA      11
5555     BBB      PPP
```

Part of my rules is only pull back the result where an OrderNo whose AAA and BBB value match. (ie. I know coming in that AAA should be 111 and BBB should be PPP).

So from the example above I should only return OrderNo 1234

Where I am struggling is to setup the query to meet this condition.

Currently I have the following code in my where clause:

```
    AND (
            -- Match AAA and BBB values.
            AJO.VALUE IN (SELECT VALUE FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE S_FILTER IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(listFilters)) AND AJO.O_FILTER = 'AAA' )                        
            AND
            AJO.VALUE IN (SELECT VALUE FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE S_FILTER IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(listFilters)) AND AJO.O_FILTER = 'BBB' )
        )
```

If I comment out the first part I get the results of all matching BBB values, and vice versa if I comment out the BBB clause.

Why is my logic failing me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pivot the table using:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
PIVOT  ( MAX( value ) FOR mycode IN ( 'AAA' AS AAA, 'BBB' AS BBB )
```

Which will give:

```
ORDERNO AAA BBB
------- --- ---
   1234 11  PPP
   4732 11
   5555     PPP
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   your_table
  PIVOT  ( MAX( value ) FOR mycode IN ( 'AAA' AS AAA, 'BBB' AS BBB )
)
WHERE AAA MEMBER OF listFilters
AND   BBB MEMBER OF listFilters;
```

Which will give:

```
ORDERNO AAA BBB
------- --- ---
   1234 11  PPP
```

**Alternative**:

You can also use the [`COLLECT` aggregation function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions024.htm) to create a collection of the values and do a set comparison using the [`SUBMULTISET` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions006.htm):

```
SELECT OrderNo
FROM   (
  SELECT OrderNo,
         CAST( COLLECT( value ) AS your_listFilter_Type ) AS vals
  FROM   your_table
  WHERE  myCode IN ( 'AAA', 'BBB' )
  GROUP BY OrderNo
)
WHERE  listFilters SUBMULTISET OF vals;
```

**Alternative 2**:

```
SELECT orderno, mycode, value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         CAST(
           COLLECT(
             CASE WHEN mycode IN ( 'AAA', 'BBB' ) THEN value END
           ) OVER ( PARTITION BY OrderNo )
           AS your_listFilter_type
         ) AS vals
  FROM   your_table t
)
WHERE  1 = 1 -- Some conditions
AND    listFilters SUBMULTISET OF vals
AND    2 = 2; -- Some more conditions
```

> Why is my logic failing me?

You are not restricting the sub-queries to have the same `OrderNo` as the outer query.

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table t
WHERE  EXISTS( SELECT 1
               FROM   your_table x
               WHERE  x.orderno = t.orderno
               AND    x.mycode  = 'AAA'
               AND    x.value   MEMBER OF listFilters )
AND    EXISTS( SELECT 1
               FROM   your_table x
               WHERE  x.orderno = t.orderno
               AND    x.mycode  = 'BBB'
               AND    x.value   MEMBER OF listFilters );
```

However this will potentially do 3 table scans whereas either of the options above will only do a single table scan.

Comment: OK ty.  Let me play around with this some.  My statement is part of an "AND" statement in my where clause.  I have other filtering that takes place that I omitted to keep the issue at hand simple.

Comment: @JDS Added in another alternative using the `COLLECT` analytic function (rather than aggregation) which should let you output the data in the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

Between `AND` clause results on an empty set (since it can not be  `AJO.O_FILTER = 'AAA'`  and  `AJO.O_FILTER = 'BBB'` on the same time). You need `OR`:

```
AJO.VALUE IN (SELECT VALUE FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE S_FILTER IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(listFilters)) AND AJO.O_FILTER = 'AAA' )                        
   OR
AJO.VALUE IN (SELECT VALUE FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE S_FILTER IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(listFilters)) AND AJO.O_FILTER = 'BBB' )
```

Comment: The OR statement give me one or the other.  I only want a result when both AAA and BBB match for a given OrderID